# What are some examples of $2$ by $2$ matrices that meet this condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Let $A$ and $B$ be $2$ by $2$ matrices such that $A^2$ $+$ $A$ $=$ $0$ and $B^2$ $+$ $B$ $=$ $0$. What is an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $(A + B)^2$ $+$ $A$ $+$ $B$ does not equal $0$?**

I am struggling to find matrices that meet the initial conditions other than the $0$ matrix. Is there a general formula through which this could be satisfied? Moreover, how would we move on to the main part after that?

Please note that this is only a sub part of a larger problem. But I need to figure this out first.

Any help?

Comment: In general: $A$ will satisfy $A^2 + A = 0$ if and only if it is diagonalizable with $0$ or $-1$ as its only eigenvalues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A=B=-I$ is one example, and it works for all sizes. Since it annihilates a square-free polynomial, a matrix satisfies the initial condition if and only if it is diagonalizable in $\Bbb C$ and its eigenvalues are all roots of that polynomial (in this case, roots of $x^2+x$).

Comment: Is annihilate a technical term out of curiosity

Comment: I don't know. I'd use it. Which one would you rather use? "To nullify"?

Comment: no I love it and want to use it in my abstract vector spaces proofs, I just want to make sure the professor won’t disapprove :)

Comment: "Annihilator" is a common term in algebra and linear algebra to identify the set of things that send stuff to zero.